# How can I make my figure resemple more the example?

Tags: stochastic-processes

Currently I'm learning about SDE's. In my course notes the following example was given for the following SDE:
This results in the following image:

\begin{array}{l}
d B_{t}=\left(-K_{1} B_{t}+s_{t}+\frac{1}{2} B_{t} \sigma^{2}\right) d t-B_{t} \sigma d W_{t} \\
B_{t_{0}}=B_{0}
\end{array}

[image]

With Python I tried to recreate the figure:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = 100
N = 10000
dt = T/N
K1 = 1
st = 3
Bt = 20
sigma = 1
y = np.zeros(N*2)
x = np.linspace(0,T,N*2)

for i in range(N*2):
    y[i] = Bt
    Bt += (-K1*Bt + st + 0.5*Bt*sigma**2)*dt - Bt*sigma*np.random.normal(0, dt)

plt.plot(x, y)
```

The values for $K_1$, $s_t$ and $\sigma$ were not given, but I think I did a OK job.

Now I want to create this figure that shows the variance and mean. How do I modify my code in order to achieve this goal?

[image]

Comment: How much does changing the y-axis help?  Right now it's zoomed out quite a bit because plotting the standard deviation makes the y-axis start from $0$

Answer (score 1):

Under the light of Monte Carlo, you can just simulate more random paths and the calculate the respective empirical mean and std.